# Best way to get all character indexes for a given phrase located in text

Tags: java, regex, string-matching, indexof

What is the best way to get all character positions of a search phrase for a given string of text?

For example, say we have `"the red cat is watching the red car stopped at the red stop sign"`

INPUT: "red"
OUTPUT: [5, 29, 52]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [indexOf](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) method of the string class:

```
String haystack = "the red cat is watching the red car stopped at the red stop sign";
String needle = "red";
int idx = 0, pos;
while( (pos = haystack.indexOf(needle,idx)) != -1) {
        System.out.println(pos+1);
        idx += pos+1;     
}
```

[See it](http://www.ideone.com/VBYkC)

Comment: Thanks for helping me find the lost needles! ;-)